# Are the new ECMAScript 6 import and export asynchronous?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Are the new ECMAScript 6 `import` and `export` asynchronous? I found this:
http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html

> #### 16.2.2 ECMAScript 6 modules
>
> The goal for ECMAScript 6 modules was to create a format that both
>   users of CommonJS and of AMD are happy with:
>
> - Similarly to CommonJS, they have a compact syntax, a preference for
>     single exports and support for cyclic dependencies.
> - Similarly to AMD, they have direct support for asynchronous loading
>     and configurable module loading.

Does it mean if I have something like

```
import * from A
import * from B

alert(1);
```

then it downloads A and B at the same time and then `alert` when both are loaded?

Comment: your question/assumption is correct, that's how it behaves. note there's a difference between transferring and running, and they all run about the same time, top-down, so that it's easy to code and read.

Comment: How can I make sure that whats downloaded from a module is within a scope of something, to not mix it with global window?

Comment: modules run under `use strict`, so there should not be accidental globals. afaik, there's no way to seal() _window_, so i'm not sure you can do what you ask, other than cleaning up after something...

Comment: Also what if I want to import something only if a certain if condition is true?

Comment: There's no support for importing in an if statement. If you only sometimes need to use a library, import the library.

Comment: You can't. ES6 modules are static imports. If you want to conditionally import, you will have to use commonJS and a bundler. http://dev.topheman.com/optimize-your-bundles-weight-with-webpack/

Comment: @topheman Only the regular `import` statement is "static". But there's an upcoming standard for `import()` and you can also use things like `System.import()` if you need more flexibility.

Comment: Here is a nice post explaining why the babel implementation of `import/export` is not spec compliant: https://medium.com/the-node-js-collection/an-update-on-es6-modules-in-node-js-42c958b890c#a704

Answer (score 2):

No, they are not. Modules are *declarative*, statically specifying *what* to import and export.

They do not specifiy *how* to import, that's the job of the module loader. Different loaders may behave differently, some of them are synchronous and others are asynchronous.

Comment: But i'm taking about ecma6 `import`... What different loaders are you talking about?

Comment: The loaders you can use to load ES5 modules.

Comment: Are you referring to commonjs or requirejs?

Comment: No, things like [System.js](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs), the [native browser module loaders](https://github.com/whatwg/loader), etc